# Food calories vs gravitational potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, potential-energy, popular-science

Imagine you could use all of the energy you have ever extracted from your food as a source of propulsion. Is the energy contained in the food you’ve eaten over the course of your lifetime enough to allow you to escape from the Earth’s gravitational pull? What do you think?
Reminder 1 J = 1 kg m2/s2
and the conversion to calories is roughly 1
nutritional calorie ≈ 4187 J.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick scribbling suggests that caloric intake for a $70\;{\rm kg}$ human over the course of $50\;{\rm yr}$ at $2500\;{\rm Cal}$ per day is enough to accelerate that person to almost $75,000\;{\rm m}/{\rm s}$. Escape velocity from Earth is about $11,000\;{\rm m}/{\rm s}$, so even with a reasonable hit for inefficiency (about $2\%$ energy efficiency is enough) it seems plausible. But certainly not practical.

Answer (score 2):

To escape Earth, you'd need to be alive for (see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gravitational%20constant%20*%20mass%20of%20earth%20*%2062%20kilograms%20%2F%20%28365%20*%20%288%20*%2010%5E6%20Joules%29%20*%20radius%20of%20earth%29))
$$
\frac{1}{365 E} \left(\frac{GMm}{R}\right) \ \mbox{years} \approx 1 \ \mbox{year},
$$
where $E \approx 2000 \times 1000 \times 4 \ J = 8 \times 10^6 \ J$ is the average daily energy intake (couldn't find a good source for a worldwide average), $G \approx 7 \times 10^{-11} \ m^3 kg^{-1} s^{-2}$ is the gravitational constant, $M \approx 6 \times 10^{24} \ kg$ is the mass of the Earth, $m \approx 6 \times 10^1 \ kg$ is the [average person's mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_weight#Average_weight_around_the_world), and $R \approx 6 \times 10^6 \ m
$ is the radius of the Earth.

Comment: I think you forgot that nutritional calories (Cal) are actually kilocalories (kcal), so you are of by a factor of 1000.